# How to read mainframe file from unix sed command?

Tags: unix, sed, mainframe

I am trying to read a mainframe file thru' 'sed' but it's not able to.
This script is being invoked from mainframe JCL so it has tcsh inbuilt.

```
sed -n '1,10p' mainframeFile
```

will yield nothing as it can't read.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a mainframe file"?

Comment: yeah it's an MVS file.

Comment: just ensure that it's a text file not binary (low values). Need to replace dots with spaces.

Comment: Well, we had attempted 'cat MFFile | sed' command earlier but it didn't yield any output only to discover that file being read had some formatting issues, I believe dots instead of spaces. After fixing the file itself, the command worked.

'sed' command also works on text file but not on binary file. The low values had to be replaced by spaces.

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you refer to mainframe file I assume you mean MVS files and not USS files as USS files are specified for `sed` like any other file.

`sed` cannot directly, you could use this hack to make it work by using `cat` and pumping this to stdout and piping.  Read below for more information on MVS Datasets and command line utilities.  It also has references on how to specify MVS datasets in USS commands like `cat`.

I tried this on a local system and it worked with this `sed` command.

`cat "//'USER1.TEST.CNTL(JOBCARD)'"`

> //        JOB (CCCCCCCC),'HOGSTROM',
>   //             MSGLEVEL=(1,1), 
>   //             MSGCLASS=O,
>   //             CLASS=A,
>   //             NOTIFY=&SYSUID

`cat "//'USER1.TEST.CNTL(JOBCARD)'" | sed 's/JOB/BOB/'`

> //        BOB (CCCCCCCC),'HOGSTROM',
>   //             MSGLEVEL=(1,1),
>   //             MSGCLASS=O,
>   //             CLASS=A,
>   //             NOTIFY=&SYSUID

Why not in `sed`?

There are limited utilities that support MVS file names on the command line.  This [article from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/usmd.htm) outlines the supported utilities.

Unfortunately, **sed** is not in the list

> The following utilities support the use of MVS™ file names.
>
> Consult the description for each utility for limitations and exceptions:
>   -  automount
>   -  c89
>   -  cp
>   -  mv
>   -  pax
>   -  tar
>   **MVS data sets that are defined with DSNTYPE=LARGE are not supported.**

This section talks about access to [MVS files in USS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/mvsds.htm)

Comment: that being said, you could always copy that file to a temporary and do what ever want with it, then copy the new file back over

Comment: I was experimenting while you commented ... I originally tried `cp` to send to stdout and then tried `cat` which worked ... we need Linux System Services

Comment: to be honest, I find a lot of this easier in JAVA batch using JZ/OS libraries. It might not be the best way, but I have found it the easiest for sure

Comment: Dovetailed Technologies [Co:Z Dataset Pipes](http://dovetail.com/products/dspipes.html) is another useful mechanism for routing "classic" MVS datasets to z/Unix utilities.

Comment: @cschneid Thanks for the link ... i didn't realize this was one of their offerings.

Comment: Well, we had attempted 'cat MFFile | sed' command earlier but it didn't yield any output only to discover that file being read had some formatting issues, I believe dots instead of spaces. After fixing the file itself, the command worked.

'sed' command also works on text file but not on binary file. The low values had to be replaced by spaces.

Thanks all for your suggestions.